# Why my icon and info on Delphi Splash Screen only shows the first time?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, splash-screen

I am developing a component package and want to display a icon and some license information about it on the Delphi XE's splash, such as the good component packages do (TMS, CnPack, etc.).

In fact I'm getting to do this through the OTA, but strangely, only immediately after the first compilation and installation, these things appear on the splash screen. After closing the Delphi and reopen nothing is displayed.

Here is an excerpt from my code that does this.

```
unit Wizards.Information;

interface

implementation

{$R *.res}

uses
  ToolsAPI, Windows, Graphics, SysUtils;

const
  ICON_SPLASH = 'SPLASHICON';
  ICON_ABOUT = 'ABOUTICON';

var
  AboutBoxServices: IOTAAboutBoxServices = nil;
  AboutBoxIndex: Integer = 0;

resourcestring
  resPackageName = 'Delphi Framework v1.0';
  resLicense = 'Mozilla Public License 1.1';
  resAboutCopyright = 'Copyright My Company Ltd.';
  resAboutTitle = 'Delphi Framework';
  resAboutDescription = 'Good description here ;)';

procedure RegisterSplashScreen;
var
  bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bmp.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, ICON_SPLASH);
    SplashScreenServices.AddPluginBitmap(resPackageName, bmp.Handle, False, resLicense);
  finally
    bmp.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure RegisterAboutBox;
var
  ProductImage: HBITMAP;
begin
  Supports(BorlandIDEServices,IOTAAboutBoxServices, AboutBoxServices);
  ProductImage := LoadBitmap(FindResourceHInstance(HInstance), ICON_ABOUT);
  AboutBoxIndex := AboutBoxServices.AddPluginInfo(resPackageName, resAboutCopyright + #13#10#13#10 + resAboutDescription, ProductImage, False, resLicense);
end;

procedure UnregisterAboutBox;
begin
  if (AboutBoxIndex <> 0) and Assigned(AboutBoxServices) then
  begin
    AboutBoxServices.RemovePluginInfo(AboutBoxIndex);
    AboutBoxIndex := 0;
    AboutBoxServices := nil;
  end;
end;

initialization
  RegisterSplashScreen;
  RegisterAboutBox;

finalization
  UnRegisterAboutBox;
end.
```

As you can see I'm trying to display some information in the Delphi XE's About Box also, and I'm getting up, but this information suffer the same problem happened with the splash screen unfortunately.

What's wrong?

Any hint is welcome!

Thanks in Advance

*The question is answered and everything seems to be working now, but any other consideration is welcome, I mean, any other answer diferent from use of `ForceDemandLoadState(dlDisable)` is welcome!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try calling `ForceDemandLoadState(dlDisable)` at the start of your register procedure.

Comment: Hello! This need to be done on both Register procedures, right? I'll try. Thankyou!

Comment: The solution works, but seems this is some form of "workaround". Is this the better form of fix for my problem? Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: I'm making a wizard with 3 special forms shown on the Repository Wizard. Even when the icon on splash screen is not shown my Wizard still working, and this makes me think there are a problem, of course, but a fixable problem. There are the need to use this workaround?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not an expert on OTA. From what I understand, Delphi has a lazy-load mechanism for design-time packages, so until something is referenced in your package it will not be loaded. This does seem like a brute-force workaround - there may be a way to get *just* your package to load at startup, but I'm not sure what you need to include (or if in fact ForceDemandLoadState applies to just your package).

Comment: Ok! This is enough to me. Thank you very much!